# Image cropping for non standard aspect ratio format

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I am facing the problem of rendering the correct image with some portion of the edges cropped out. I can observe this only for non-standard aspect ratio.
In my case width is 1228 and height is 972 which is yielding an aspect ratio of 1.26.

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);


float vx = float(m_uiImageWidth) / float(m_uiImageWidth);
float vy = float(m_uiImageHeight) / float(m_uiImageWidth);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, m_uiImageWidth, m_uiImageHeight, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_arrayBufferVS1);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);

    //glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.36f);
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.358f);

    //Normal
    if(m_bContextMenuNormal)
        glRotatef(180, 1, 0, 0);
    else if (m_bContextMenuRotate180 && m_bContextMenuMirror) 
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else if(m_bContextMenuMirror)
        glRotatef(180, 0, 0, 0);
    else if(m_bContextMenuRotate180)
        glRotatef(180, 0, 1, 0);
    
    glScalef(1, -1, 1);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); //top right
        glVertex3f(vx, vy, 0.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); // left top
        glVertex3f(-vx, vy, 0.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); //left bottom
        glVertex3f(-vx, -vy, 0.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); //right bottom
        glVertex3f(vx, -vy, 0.0f);

    glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

This is my code snippet. It would be a great help if anyone points out the mistake I have made and suggestions to fix.

Comment: As far as I can tell from your code, you always crop when `vy > 1`. The visible range you have is from -1 to 1 on each axis. When height > width, you will draw points outside of the screen.

Comment: I have made a mistake in posting the question at the first instance. width of the image is 1228 and height is 972

Answer (score 0):

modify your calls to `glTexCoord2f`, the decimal values are interpolated between the four vertexes and then multiplied by the width and height of the image to calculate the coordinates of each pixel from the texture to draw to the screen. if you want to crop the left and right of your image with an aspect ratio of 1.26 into a square you would use the following texture coordinates:

```
glTexCoord2f(1.0f - 0.13f, 1.0f); //top right
glTexCoord2f(0.0f + 0.13f, 1.0f); // left top
glTexCoord2f(0.0f + 0.13f, 0.0f); //left bottom
glTexCoord2f(1.0f - 0.13f, 0.0f); //right bottom
```

0.13 * 1228 is 159.64 pixels, and when you remove 159.64 pixels from either side of your 1228 pixel wide texture the remaining portion of the image is 972 pixels wide, meaning the aspect ratio of the pixels drawn will be 1:1 because your texture is 972 pixels tall